# Specify at run-time where to create or open Derby embedded database

Tags: java, web-applications, derby

I want to be able to define the folder where a Derby embedded database will be created after I start my application (which will someday migrate to a web application). The only way I know of setting this folder is by setting the `derby.system.home` system property -- but this property is read at JVM start-time, and is never refreshed (see [reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cscv/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cloudscape.doc/rtunproper32066.html))

Is there any work-around that does not involve stopping and restarting the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to specify the path in your Derby URL?

Something like

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/home/viv/mydb");
```

Comment: duh - should have thought of that sooner. Works like a charm.

Comment: How do you gracefully handle the condition "if database doesn't yet exist"?